# Deal with highly unbalanced data classes

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, unbalanced-classes

I got this horrible(hope you'll find the good in it) dataset, with 15 classes. 
Any suggestion to deal with it? 
I was wondering to group at least into 3 classes, however the first one is tremendously populated.
Thanks

```
          CLASSES   tot
            <int> <int>
 1              1  3122
 2              2   716
 3              3   481
 4              4   288
 5              5   216
 6              6   150
 7              7   106
 8              8    86
 9              9    47
10             10    40
11             11    34
12             12    27
13             13    13
14             14    19
15             15    18
```

Comment: It's hard to say anything with no idea of what the classes signify, what other data you have available, or what you're trying to do. Provide [context](http://arfer.net/w/statqgl).

Comment: You can do the oversampling or undersampling of classes to make it a balanced distribution. More details of the problem would be better.

Comment: Ok thank you! I thought i needed to do some oversampling.